# Как зайти на сервер по ссылке с клиента discord py?

Tags: python, discord, token

Как зайти на сервер в дискорде по токену используя приглашение пользователя например [https://discord.gg/приглашение](https://discord.gg/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).
Хочу сделать чтобы токен заходил по ссылке с помощью переменной например `discordinvite=input()`.

Comment: Так нельзя. Боты в дискорде авторизуются на серверах отдельными методами, не как пользователи